# Recommend an intro to binary embedding algorithm in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

I'm working on my final year project which will establish an reasonable upper bound for one of the bandwidth problem in graph theory. I found difficulty on understanding an algorithm that construct an binary embedding for a tree. The paper lacks essential guide to terminology and I'm beginner at graph theory.

Can you recommend a friendly intro to such algorithm?

Definition of binary embedding:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a "binary embedding of a tree." There are many papers about embedding binary trees into graphs. For example, embedding binary trees into d-dimensional hypercubes.

Comment: @JosephMalkevitch Added definition of binary embedding.